# Can't set frame width and height with [OpenCV] cv2.VideoCapture.set()

Tags: python, opencv, video, kinect, video-capture

I am trying to reduce the frame/window size of my video capture to `320x180` but I can't seem to do it. I am using a Windows Kinect for Xbox One and its connected to my pc using an adapter.

I have tried setting the `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` to 320 and `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT` to 180 but once I try and get the values it returns 1920 and 1080. I have also tried installing and reinstalling the Kinect SDK and drivers.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 180)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 25)

print(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print(vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

while True:
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[print output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elieZ.jpg)

I would like help in knowing where the problem stems from and hopefully get a fix.

Comment: I know little about any Microsoft product, but that resolution doesn't seem to feature in the list of resolutions Kinects can produce.

Comment: I tried the resolutions 640x480 and 1280x720 but the width and height still defaulted to 1920x1080. I have found a thread that might have a similar problem to mine but I have no idea how to implement the solution in windows. https://answers.opencv.org/question/217208/opencv-410-not-changing-brightness/. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea is to resize the frame without having to worry about setting the default frame size. Instead of using `cv2.VideoCapture().set()`, you can use [`cv2.resize()`](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) to resize the original `1920x1080` frame into `320x180`. But this method does not maintain aspect ratio. If you wanted to maintain aspect ratio, you can use the [`imutils`](https://pypi.org/project/imutils/) library. The `imutils.resize()` function resizes the frame and maintains aspect ratio. Change the `width` parameter to your desired resolution

```
import cv2
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=320)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: nice solution. I am transferring cv  image<-> qtlabel pixmap and it solved my need.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I have found that solved this problem

When you try to set random resolution, opencv sets nearest resolution if that resolution is not available.

You can run below command to find out all the available resolutions of your webcam.

```
uvcdynctrl -f
```

And set those resolutions only. (my webcam resolutions: 1280x720, 640x480, 640x360)

```
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
```

Reference: https://techoverflow.net/2018/12/18/how-to-set-cv2-videocapture-image-size/

Answer (score 0):

There's another method you can resize your screen size using cv2

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

width = 300
height = 300

new_image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height))

cv2.imwrite("new_image.jpg", new_image)
```