# How can I get the ROI frame in the full frame?

Tags: python, opencv, frame, webcam, roi

I try to play a ROI of the window as shown in the picture by receiving the image with the Webcam.

**- Conditions**

**1) The size of the main window is 400x300.**

**2) ROI is set to 320x240 at (30,30).**

**3) Put a red border on the ROI.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V7IT.jpg)

Here is how I did it:

1. Create a mask with the same size as the frame.
2. Make a square ROI on the mask.
3. Use cv2.add to synthesize frame and mask, and assign it to dst.
4. Check dst with cv2.imshow.

Here is code

```
import numpy as np, cv2
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if capture.isOpened() is None:
    raise Exception("Camera not connected")

capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 300)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 400)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    
    if not ret:
        break

    mask = np.zeros(frame.shape[:2], np.uint8)

    cv2.rectangle(mask, (30, 30), (320, 240), (0, 0, 255), -1)

    dst = cv2.add(frame, frame, mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("dst", dst)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break
    

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**But, I don't solve it**

Any other way?

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: why you dont crop the input frame directly and use it ?

Answer (score 0):

A mask has only one channel. Change this line:

```
cv2.rectangle(mask, (30, 30), (320, 240), 255, -1)
```

Additionally you shouldn't use `cv2.add()` because it changes your image. Better do:

```
dst = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
```

And this is how you can simply crop the image, if you need to:

```
dst = frame[30:240, 30:320]
```

Regarding the setting of frame width and height please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664597/18667225).